# How can I scroll to the bottom from a KnockoutJS update hook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a set of elements in a scrolling div and I want to scroll to the bottom automatically when knockout changes the data. I want to do it like this:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.autoScroll = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        // Scroll to bottom (doesn't work).
        $(element).parent().scrollTop($(element).parent()[0].scrollHeight);
    },
};
```

but it doesn't scroll all the way to the bottom, presumably because the DOM hasn't updated at this point, so I have to do it like this:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.autoScroll = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        // Scroll to bottom after DOM has updated.
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(element).parent().scrollTop($(element).parent()[0].scrollHeight);
        }, 500);
    },
};
```

How do I do it properly without the setTimeout hack?

This works but in my more complex Bootstrap themed div it doesn't scroll all the way to the end:
http://jsfiddle.net/9tzrushn/

Comment: Can you post a fiddle demonstrating your example please? Also a bit more narrative on how you want this binding to behave, for example should the scroll happen when the observable bound to the element changes?

Comment: @AnishPatel http://jsfiddle.net/9tzrushn/

Comment: can you post some of your html and css please? Is the list in your actual implementation fixed height too?

Comment: Show the HTML of your "more complex Bootstrap themed"